# How I can install apk automatically when the sdcard put on?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I have not any idea. How can I install apk automatically when the sdcard put on?

However, I have got an problem, When I register the receiver that listened to the `ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED` in AndroidManifest.xml   Em... I create a  Receiver that extends `BroadcastReceive`, I override `OnReceive()`. But, finally, the Receiver can not get any Action. Here is my code. Frustrating!!!!!

```
<receiver android:name=".SdcardPutOnListener"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_MEDIA_CHECKING" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_NOFS" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class SdcardPutOnListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final static String TAG = "SdcardPutOnListener";
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "receive broadcast " + intent.getAction()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create an app that watches for the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` broadcast, then looks at external storage in a well-known spot for an APK file, then calls `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the path to that APK file, with the right MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

If you are expecting this to be built into the operating system, it is not.

Comment: However, I have got an problem, When I register the receiver that listened to the ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED in _AndroidManifest.xml_. Then, i create the Receiver extends BroadcastReceive, override the OnReceive(). Finally, the Receiver can not get any Action. Here is my code. I have not find the answer.